# Applying Elements To Random Positions Within Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning

I am trying to position some Font Awesome stars randomly across a section, and the amount of stars depends on the amount of elements in the array.

I have written the following code but it is not working.  I have tested that both jQuery and Font Awesome are correctly loaded.

Can anyone kindly advise?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var star = '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';  // Define star to insert later
        var starArray = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana"];  // Define array
        var section = document.getElementById('section-for-stars'); // Get id of section where stars are to be randomly places
        var width = section.offsetWidth; // Get section width
        var height = section.offsetHeight; // Get section height
        for (var i=0; i<starArray.length;i++) { // for loop array.length output star onto .section-contact
            var posx = Math.floor(Math.random()*width);  // Define random position x
            var posy = Math.floor(Math.random()*height);  // Define random position y
        star.appendTo(section).css({   // Append
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':posx+'px',
            'top':posy+'px',
        });
        }
        });
```

Comment: What `is not working` means? Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: Id be unique in HTML. you appended same ids in for loop

Comment: Create a new star (new `i` element) in the loop and then append it

Comment: Why on earth has this been downvoted?  I always follow the rules, always ask politely, hardly ever ask a question and now I am banned for asking questions.  Is it only the elite of coders that are allowed in here?

Thanks to those that helped above.

Comment: @JamesWinfield Try not to let it get to you, people here are VERY picky and almost mean about how they help people most of the time. Keep posting questions, just try to be more specific (i.e. including error outputs or screenshots of behaviour).

Comment: @MarcBosse Thanks!  I had to open another account as I couldn't post on my original one, though I don't think I understood the point of SO at first.  All good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find a way to have both elements start and section as html dom elements and not string. then only you can use append method.

here I have used a fake div so that i can get element as DOM, you can even use $(star as string html)

```
  var div = document.createElement('div');
                    div.innerHTML = star;
                    var element = div.childNodes[0];
        console.log(element)
         $(element).appendTo(section).css({   // Append
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':posx+'px',
        'top':posy+'px',
    });
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1721/

Comment: Thanks that is perfect - I wasn't far away in the end.

Comment: Yes it was just HTML dom elements needed instead of HTML string